# Importing members from internal files will throw “Module not found: Error: Can't resolve”

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to import a `function` and an `interface` from internal files of `@ionic/core`. Those members are not exported directly by the module, however, they are exported in the file `dist/types/utils/transition`.

Using them on vscode doesn't generate any error and I am able to use them:

[image: No error here]

However, when I use `ng build` I got `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve` and `Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration`.

Also, I have tried with `../../node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition` without successful results.

Which is the best way to include them? ([File in github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/core/src/utils/transition/index.ts))

**UPDATED:**

Importing only the interface `TransitionOptions` it works, however, the function `getIonPageElement` cannot be imported. It seems to be exported in `index-356fa4e5` and I cannot import it directly.

Full error log:

```
    ERROR in ./src/app/app-page-transitions.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition' in '/home/user/Projects/new-project/src/app'
resolve '../../node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition' in '/home/user/Projects/new-project/src/app'
  using description file: /home/user/Projects/new-project/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/package.json (relative path: ./dist/types/utils/transition)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition is not a file
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition.tsx doesn't exist
      .mjs
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition.mjs doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        existing directory
          using path: /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index
            using description file: /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/package.json (relative path: ./dist/types/utils/transition/index)
              no extension
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index doesn't exist
              .ts
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index.ts doesn't exist
              .tsx
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index.tsx doesn't exist
              .mjs
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index.mjs doesn't exist
              .js
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index.js doesn't exist
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition.ts]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition.tsx]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition.mjs]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition.js]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index.ts]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index.tsx]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index.mjs]
[/home/user/Projects/new-project/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/types/utils/transition/index.js]
 @ ./src/app/app-page-transitions.ts 2:0-96 11:20-37 16:51-68
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```